# Run file system operations as root

Tags: node.js, sudo, sudoers

I have a node application which is a worker, performing various tasks on a local machine, including a lot of file system operations. The app receives task instructions from a separate "control" app over HTTPS.

The app runs as an unprivileged user, but occasionally it needs to execute certain operations with root privileges.

These operations include:

- Mounting and unmounting drives
- Formatting drives
- Reading files from external drives where file permissions are sometimes set so the unprivileged user cannot read them

These operations involve both running commands with `child_process.exec()` / `.spawn()` and file system read operations using the `fs` module.

Obviously, running the whole app as root isn't wise for security reasons. But it sometimes needs to be able to "upgrade" its privileges to root.

What is the best way of doing this?

I've played around with having a separate node app running as root on the same machine, which the main worker app can communicate with over HTTP and send it certain commands which need to be executed as root. But of course this opens a new attack surface on the root app. It's also a pain when the root operation is reading large files (10-100 GB) from the file system, that those files then have to be streamed over HTTP back to the main worker app.

I imagine there's a more practical and secure way to achieve this, perhaps using `sudoers`. I can't imagine I'm the first to encounter this problem, but I've not found any solutions on the web.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I think most people opt to let node run with `sudo` and instead try to manage security by requiring authentication first before proceeding with a potentially dangerous operation. This is much easier to manage, and there's already [a web standard](https://jwt.io/) developed around this practice.

Comment: Thanks @Liongold. The JWT standard is really interesting. However, I'm still loathe to run the app as root if there's any way to avoid it. Even if a user of the app is authenticated, if there's a security hole in my API code somewhere, they might be able to cause operations to be run which they're not meant to. Obviously the scope for damage is much greater if those operations are run as root.